# How to animate whole LinearLayout and its inside views Android?

Tags: android, animation, view, fadeout

I have a LinearLayout, which contains some ImageButtons.
I want to fadeout the LinearLayout and its children. I tried to use AlphaAnimation.
If I start animation with ImageButton inside LinearLayout, everything works fine. But when I start animation with LinearLayout instead of ImageButtons, nothing happens. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Refer to this link:http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Animation/Animationfadeinfadeout.htm

Comment: Thank you. But it is not what I want. I want to fade out the whole LinearLayout and everything inside it.

Comment: do you mean you want to fade out the whole activity or is LinearLayout a part of xml ?

Comment: I want to fadeout the whole activity.

Answer (score 2):

You can try following animation xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
  <alpha
      android:fromAlpha="0.0"
      android:toAlpha="1.0"
      android:duration="5000"/>
</set>
```

and then can try following code snippet

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
layout.startAnimation(anim);
```

Its worked fine for me.

Comment: Hi Manish. mainLayout is the layout of whole activity?

Comment: yes mainLayout is the layout of whole activity which contains one image view and button.

Comment: Hi Sunshinetpu, is it worked for you? If yes then you can accept answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply Pass android:animateLayoutChanges=true to Linear Layout that hold all layouts, you will get desired results